# How could I stop execution of onClick event for a specific element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and I have a TableRow element, which has onClick event. But now I have to add a checkbox inside the table. The checkbox is wrapped in TableCell element, which is part of the TableRow. Now when I click on the checkbox it is triggering the onClick event, which I do not want to happen. Is it possible somehow to stop the propagation of the function !? Could I disable onClick for that specific cell and if yes, will it be possible to click on the checkbox? Or I should do some magic trick inside the function call if the element is with some specific ID for example not to be executed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697735/prevent-checkbox-and-clickable-table-row-conflict

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I used if event.target.id === 'something' stop propagation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()` in the checkbox click handler so that the parent element's click event is not fired.

```
function MyCheckbox() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ....
  }

  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} />
      Click me
    </label>
  );
}
```